# How to get update record based on given record in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sql-update

I want to get record from DB based on given date value. I used Timestamp as coulmn type. I used query as

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE LAST_UPDT_S = to_date('23-AUG-12')
```

Getting empty table. where as records were present in the table.

Please, sort out me from this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get for last_updt_s between to_date('23-AUG-12') and to_date('24-AUG-12') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your table contains dates with time part so try to use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE Trunc(LAST_UPDT_S) = to_date('23-AUG-12')
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.. its wroking fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE LAST_UPDT_S = to_date('23-AUG-12', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

**[SEE: TO_DATE Manual](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)**

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's better to use a time range - this opens the possibility of using an index if one exists:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE LAST_UPDT_S >= DATE '2012-08-23'
  AND LAST_UPDT_S < DATE '2012-08-24'
```

(Also, it's better to not use TO_DATE without specifying the date format, otherwise it will use whatever the current session's NLS setting happens to be.)